# What is the result of running 'crontab *'?

Tags: terminal, cron

I've accidentally ran '`crontab *`'. Afterwards, crontab -l and, possibly, crontab -e stopped working properly.

Can someone more knowledgeable in cron help me explain what would happen if `'crontab *'` command is ran?

I ran `crontab -l | grep *` and very few cronjobs showed up. I also ran `crontab -e` in order to edit the crontab file and it gives me the `"Error detected while procedssing 'pathway'"` message and `"E518: Unknown option: foldmehod=marker"` error. It brings me to `/tmp/crontab*` where * denotes an attempt to create a cron file at tmp folder.

I expect the output of `crontab -l | grep "name"` to output something but the output doesn't show anything. I suspect it's me running crontab *.

Comment: `crontab *` would expand to `crontab` and then all the files in the current directory. If you check `man crontab`, you'll see that `crontab file` installs a crontab from the file `file`. Your errors seem to be related to vim and not really crontab; to see the crontab for the current user, run `crontab -l` without grepping.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the result would be `crontab` attempting to install every file that `*` would have expanded to. Since you did not specify a user with -u first, it would have defaulted to whatever user you were executing the command as. The good news is this only messed up your private crontab.

Cron uses two different crontabs; a system-wide crontab at `/etc/crontab` and the private, user-specific crontabs at `/var/spool/cron`. When you use `crontab`, for example as root, to install a new file, those changes are actually made to `/var/spool/cron/root`, not the global crontab found at `/etc/crontab`.

Thus the damage is mitigated to the private crontab of whichever user ran that command, which you can most likely safely remove and rebuild if necessary; but whatever is inside of that private crontab is going to be junk.